# How do I map a list of objects from an HTTP API to a list of strings?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to use the merge operator is given below. I want to put only 'Mr' before login but I am getting an error, your help is much appreciated, thank you

```
  let data=this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users');
  let output=data.pipe(map(data=>{'Mr, '+data.login}));
            output.subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment, the API returns an array of users. You therefore need to use the JavaScript array `map` operator inside the rxjs `map` to transform each individual user to the required string:

```
let data = this.http.get<any[]>('https://api.github.com/users');
let output = data.pipe(map(users => users.map(user => 'Mr, ' + user.login)));

output.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-map-github-users?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you @wlf, it works :)  I gave accepted your answer and gave you +1 
Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

you have used the operators correctly. Pipe and then using map is correct if you want to add some logic to the data you fetch using the api.

When you use the arrow function, if you use block then you have to add the **return** word.
If you have only one statement, you can directly write that.

So just replace your code with the following lines:

```
 let data=this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users').pipe(map(data=>{
    data.forEach((ele)=>ele.login = 'Mr ,'+ele.login};
     return data
  };
         data.subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: it says, "Property 'login' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)"

Comment: Okay I have edited the answer

Comment: It's because the API retrieves an array of users and the previous answer and this one assume it's a single object.

Comment: Yeah, the api should return single object. But when the api is used to get profile. It should return single object, as the there would be single user logged in.

Comment: still remains the same, no change

Comment: what is your api returns?

Comment: This is what my API returns, I want to grab that JSON data and transfer the login Property by prefixing 'Mr' string, that's all, here is the link to that
 https://api.github.com/users

Comment: As the api is returning the array of objects, you have to run the loop to update the value.
I have edited the answer accordingly.